# Building NDK with tess-two using Cygwin-terminal continues to fail and stop

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

Well, I'm working on a mobile application project (Android), and (unfortunately) I need to use Tesseract OCR and so I need to install NDK.

Any way, I'm working on Windows Vista x64, Android SDK 4.1.2 API16. I've downloaded NDK r8 and unzipped it to D:/Android_NDK

I got the tess-two, extracted it's files in the path: C:/Tess-two/tess-two-master

I also got Cygwin setup.exe, ran it, installed files into C:/Cygwin, and got the gdb, gcc-core, gcc-g++, make, swig libraries, andevery thing was alright until I've tried to build the ndk using cygwin I got the following:

1- the first trial to build it started to show records on the cygwin screen, and in the last it gave this:

```
SharedLibrary  : liblept.so
d:/android_ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.
exe: cannot find ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/liblept.so' failed
make: ***[obj/local/armeabi/liblept.so] Error 1
```

2- second try show me this:

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: c:/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pix.o.d:1: multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

3- after that it continues to show me this :

```
obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pix.o.d:1:  ***multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Whats wrong? what is the problem ??

Your help is much appreciated.